# A group of $15$ boys plucked a total of $100$ apples. Prove that two of those boys plucked the same number of apples.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A group of $15$ boys plucked a total of $100$ apples. Prove that two of those boys plucked the same number of apples.

My answer is:

First distribute $90$ apples so that each will have $6$ apples.
Now we have $100-90 = 10$ apples. Now we are distributing these many apples between two each will get $5$ apples so the ans is $2$ boys will get $11$ apples each and other $13$ boys will get $6$ apples each... Is this Proof correct ????

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is incorrect.

Suppose that each boy plucked a different number of apples.  Then the smallest total the group of boys could have plucked is 
$$0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 105$$
However, they collectively plucked just $100$ apples.  Hence, two boys must have plucked the same number of apples.

Comment: but how should I assign zero apples to some one ??

Comment: The question tells us to assume that the $15$ boys collectively plucked $100$ apples.  If we assume, for the sake the sake of contradiction, that each boy plucked a different number of apples, then we have to assign $15$ different non-negative integers to the number of apples the boys plucked.  The smallest such total is the one I gave above.  If all the boys plucked a different positive number of apples, the smallest possible number of apples they could have plucked is $120$, which again results in a contradiction.

Comment: @SourasekharBanerjee It is quite easy to imagine a boy picking $0$ apples. He decided to have a nap in the sun instead . The question did not state that each boy picked a certain number of apples, just that between all $15$ of them, the ones who happened to pick apples and those who didn't, $100$ were collected in total.

Comment: yeah... my concept is now clear ...